# Equaling certain text parts of two different text files and making changes

Tags: c#, file, replace

I'm creating an app which shortly grabs two files from the internet, checks them and creates third file. The part of grabbing part is done, so at the moment I have two files.

First one is a .txt file which contais text like this:

```
Order Code|Stock
ACREPAIR|1031
AF813|18
AF823|12
AFCOB11|21
AFCS300|33
AFCS3000|1
AFEM4|5
AFOMNI|17
AFOX2|-3
AFOX3|-3
AFROD|28
AFSENSOR|50
AFUF21|24
AN00001|-1
AN00002|21
AN00003|4
AN00004|4
AN00005|9
...
```

Text in every line of this file is the code of a certain item and stock of an item (how many products is available at the moment). There are hundreds of thousands of such lines

Then I have another file which is also a .txt and is formatted like this:

```
Action,CategoryPath,ID,Name,Code,Stock
"Product","Home > Opto-electronics > LED > Standard LED, Multicolour",2226,"KINGBRIGHT LED, 3MM, HE-RED/GRN L-93WEGW","SC07621",202
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2228,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 10K0 CRCW040210K0JNEAIF","RE06211",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2229,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 3R90 CRCW04023R90JNEAIF","RE06212",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2230,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 2R70 CRCW04022R70JNEAIF","RE06220",25
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2231,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 33R0 CRCW040233R0JNEAIF","RE06221",0
"Product","Home > Resistors > Fixed",2232,"VISHAY DRALORIC RESISTOR, 0402, 5%, 100R CRCW0402100RJNEAIF","RE06226",0
"Product","Home > IC's > Comparators",2234,"STMICROELECTRONICS IC, COMPARATOR DUAL, DIP8, 393 LM393N","SC10207",57
"Product","Home > IC's > Amplifiers > Operational",2237,"STMICROELECTRONICS OP AMP, QUAD JFET, DIP14 TL084CN","SC07929",82
"Product","Home > IC's > Amplifiers > Audio Power",2239,"NATIONAL SEMICONDUCTOR AMP, AUDIO 0.25W, DIP8, 386 LM386N-1","SC08430",83
"Product","Home > IC's > Microcontrollers",2241,"MICROCHIP 8BIT FLASH MCU, 12F675, DIP8 PIC12F675-I/P","ACREPAIR",16
...
```

And here comes my problem. I need my application to grab a line from first file, take the code and stock separately, then find the matching code in the second file and compare the stock values. If they are not the same in second file, the stock would be replaced with value of stock from first file. But if the values are same, the line which contains the code and same value of stock in second file should be removed (replaced with nothing).

The parts which need some explanation:

1. How to read first file by getting couple variables which consist of code ex. **ACREPAIR** and stock ex. 1031
2. How to find the line in second file with that code which would look like this: *"Product","Home > IC's > Microcontrollers",2241,"MICROCHIP 8BIT FLASH MCU, 12F675, DIP8 PIC12F675-I/P","**ACREPAIR**",16* and that 16 would be replaced by 1031 or if values are same that line would be removed from second file.

I would be very thankful for suggestions or even snippets on how to do that.

Comment: for starters you can read the first file with code like this
string FilePath = @"c:\yourFile.txt";
var arrData = File.ReadLines(FilePath).Select(line => 
line.Split('|')).ToArray();

Comment: that's enough to get you started.. you need to show what code you have actually tried on your own..

Comment: How do you link "SC09220" with "ACREPAIR" in the 2 example files?

Comment: What happens if the same code appears twice in the first file, and as a result of the first appearance the line is removed from second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Txt file awalys contain the Product code and Stock count at the end this should do the trick.

This will probabbly perform pretty slow if your text files are large but you can refactor as you need but this should be a good start point.

```
List<string[]> stock = new List<string[]>(File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Stock.txt").Select(line => line.Split('|')));
List<string[]> products = new List<string[]>(File.ReadAllLines("G:\\Products.txt").Select(line => line.Split(',')));

products.ForEach(p =>
{
    // since not all arrays in this case are the same lenght, we will go backwards from the end
    int productStockIndex = Array.IndexOf(p, p.Last());

    // product name is before the stock count
    int productNameIndex = productStockIndex - 1;

    // get product name to find in Stock.txt and remove extra quotes from product name
    string productName = p[productNameIndex].Replace("\"", "");

    // check if Stock.txt contains the product
    if (stock.Any(s => s[0] == productName))
    {
        // Update the stock count
        p[productStockIndex] = stock.First(stk => stk[0] == productName)[1];
    }       
});
```

Save file....

Answer (score 3):

I hope that this can be of any help to get started. The `Skip` calls are done to skip the header line of the files. Be aware that this code can be optimized in many ways (using a `HashSet` instead of an array for `compareTo`, avoiding hardcoding split indexes, etc.) but I believe that it's your responsibility to do that.

```
var items = File.ReadAllLines("file1.txt").
    Skip(1).
    Select(s =>
    {
        var strings = s.Split('|');
        if (strings.Length != 2) throw new FormatException();
        return new {Code = strings[0], Stock = Convert.ToInt32(strings[1])};
    }).
    ToArray();
var compareTo = File.ReadAllLines("file2.txt").
    Skip(1).
    Select(s =>
    {
        var strings = s.Split(',');
        if (strings.Length != 6) throw new FormatException();
        return new {Code = strings[4].Trim('"'), Stock = Convert.ToInt32(strings[5])};
    }).
    ToArray();
//You can use Intersect after having defined your EqualityComparer, 
//avoid anonymous types in your final code
foreach (var item in items.Where(i => compareTo.Any(i2 => i.Code == i2.Code)))
{
    //Operate, be aware that compareTo is dissociated from your original file
    //So you'll have to adapt the above approach for your needs.
}
```

Comment: +1 good starting point. BTW I think you need to remove quotes when parsing Code from second file

Comment: Eve, Im very thankful for the code, but I got some questions about it. I need to create file which looks exact as second, but with uodated stock count, and if stock is same in first and second file, there wouldnt be line of that code, so now Im asuming I need to also to get CategoryPath,ID,Name strings aswel, and Im doing it like that: `return new { Path = strings[2].Trim('"'), Id = Convert.ToInt32(strings[3]), Name = strings[4].Trim('"'), Code = strings[5].Trim('"'), Stock = Convert.ToInt32(strings[6]) };` Is it ok?

Comment: And in before //Operate I will create new .txt file and in //Operate place I will format lines using strings mentioned above and write them to file, is it a good plan?

Comment: @Technically, you wouldn't have to extract all data from the second file. You could just find the indices of the lines that need to be updated/removed and then process the file. What you've mentioned is good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know how your C# skills are, I will just give you a roadmap.

Both files seem very different on the first sight, but if you look closer, you'll see that structurally they are very similar: Both files are "comma separated".
The only differences are the separator (`|` against `,`) and the amount of columns, i.e. in the second file you have columns you don't need.

So a possible algorithm could be:

1. Read the first file into memory and use `string.Split()` to get the name/value pairs for each line.
2. Read the second file also into memory (I hope the files aren't too big for that) and use also `string.Split()` to get all column values, including those you don't actually need. You need them for writing the whole file in (6).
3. Close the file handles on both files! This is important for overwrite it in (6).
4. Iterate through the lines of the second file and for each line, search for the equivalent entry 
   in the first file's lines.
5. Now you can compare the values and do what you want (change the value of second file, delete the whole line, etc). Beware of the quotation marks in file 2 while comparing/changing!
6. Open a write handle for file 2 and overwrite the file, printing the (changed!) list of lines of file 2 in the proper format into the new file. For generating the CSV-like format you can use `string.Join()`.

Comment: The files have hundreds of thousands lines, so I gues they are to big for this metod (at least for mine pc :)), still thanks for the some suggesgtions as in 6th ppoint.